# Typescript: Omitting translated properties

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have interfaces that can be translated - they have the `nameDe` and `nameFr` properties for example. Currently I'm trying to build a function that returns the object with `name` only in the users language.

This is what I have so far - it works for the translated properties but not the "non-translated":

```
type TranslatedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer Name}De` ? `${Name}` : never]: T[K extends `${infer Name}De` ? K : never];
};

interface Car {
  nameDe: string,
  nameFr: string,
  price: number
}

const carWithUserLang: TranslatedObject<Car> = {
  name: 'Make Model Trim',
  price: 50000 // --> Type '{ name: string; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TranslatedObject<Car>'.
}
```

How can I make this run?
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-h7ghdn?file=index.ts&view=editor

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1xgKW) meet your needs? Please test against your use cases. If it works for you let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] the example code in the question to demonstrate the unsatisfied use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you want `TranslatedObject<T>` to strip `"De"` and `"Fr"` off of the ends of key names, if they exist, and otherwise leave them alone.  If so then this is purely a [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) operation that doesn't change the property value types.  Like this:

```
type TranslatedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer Name}${"De" | "Fr"}` ? Name : K]: T[K];
};
```

It uses a [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) within a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to strip off any `"De"` or `"Fr"` suffix.  The check `` K extends `${infer Name}${"De" | "Fr"}` `` tries to match `K` to something that starts with some arbitrary string and ends in `"De" | "Fr"`; if it succeeds, then `Name` is inferred to be that arbitrary initial string.  So then the resulting key type evaluates to `Name` if the parsing succeeded, or `K` if it failed.

That results in the type you were expecting:

```
interface Car {
  nameDe: string,
  nameFr: string,
  price: number
}

type TranslatedCar = TranslatedObject<Car>;
/* type TranslatedCar = {
    name: string;
    price: number;
} */
```

---

Note that there are some interesting edge cases, like what happens if your two keys have different value types:

```
type Weird = TranslatedObject<{
  oopsDe: string;
  oopsFr: number;
  other: boolean;
}>

/* type Weird = {
    oops: string | number; // <-- becomes union
    other: boolean;
} /
```

That might be what one would expect, or it might not. The point is that one should always thoroughly test against one's use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgQCYHkBGAVhAMbAA8MAfFALxQDeAUFFANoDSUAlklANYQQAewBmsKAhRQuEAB5Yk2aQAMAJA16iIcKADkEAWwgBfDQCIAIhHNQAPlHMAxOOZMqoAfn1HoALhkAXQCYTkCAbiYTSKZeLDhRBBJoAGEEXWZWJF9rAJRgOF4AcwAaFihs4xc8guKy1jBC5ICkAFdDfB0opiZQSFhEVAwsbDTdenhkdEwcAmIycjGqSIB6ACooPuhJoZnR9LpGcqzfGsKkIsjWBqaIFvbOuEiTKDWVnpJhVGAoEnSAdW4wAAFgBVFA6AAyyCKIUG0xGc1IFCWh0yFVOUAA5ABZBCCKA44TYCBoAbcQxY+pQRrcZpQACsAAYWUyoCsVlAALRcmgwcDQLEMDHGM7FcI0273Do6CUmLE8aRIYQ-KQobhFbL4NDQYDCTYC7E7BGzIjIxbpKhYgB03V6hv+EG4cGwh2Nw1N8wo6OEwjAKFyUHy50u5V9-uqFQesrDIJ0AXwvp1yGeVB66wN-Udztd9HRrHDKDFF3sUZlT2OUBVwPjUETwmTSGe7KAA)

Comment: Very nice, thanks for writing it up!
Could you please further explain how the `infer Name` part works? I have a basic understanding of `K extends every property with language suffixes matching a pattern` but am not sure if that actually is the way it should be read.

Comment: Sort of? I added a bit more explanation; for more details you can read the description in [ms/TS#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) which implemented template literal types and how they behave with `infer`.

Comment: bonus question: how could we do this with nested objects? Let's say `Car` has this property: `gimmicks: Gimmick[]` and again `Gimmick` has translated properties.

Comment: It's not really feasible to try to answer followup questions in comments.  Maybe you want to open a new post for it? That also has the advantage that if I can't answer it, other people will see it (I doubt many people are watching these comments).