# Typescript: how to use conditional type inference and template literal types in nested objects

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

In [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407242/typescript-omitting-translated-properties) I was provided with a great way to strip properties like `nameDe` and `nameFr` from a type and simply get `name`. Shout out @jcalz!

Now my use case got a little more complex - I have nested translated interfaces:

```
type TranslatedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer Name}${'De' | 'Fr'}` ? Name : K]: T[K];
};

interface Gimmick {
  nameDe: string;
  nameFr: string;
}

interface Car {
  nameDe: string;
  nameFr: string;
  price: number;
  gimmicks: Gimmick[];
}

const tcar: TranslatedObject<Car> = {
  name: 'Car name',
  price: 69,
  gimmicks: [{ name: 'seat ventilation' }], // Error: Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Gimmick'.
};
```

Notice how `name: 'Car name',` works properly but the nested `Gimmick` with value `{ name: 'seat ventilation' }` does not.
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gm3plg?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty straightforward. Just call `TranslatedObject` recursively if the property is an object:

```
type TranslatedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer Name}${'De' | 'Fr'}`
    ? Name
    : K]: T[K] extends object ? TranslatedObject<T[K]> : T[K];
};
```

Usage:

```
const tcar: TranslatedObject<Car> = {
  name: 'Car name',
  price: 69,
  gimmicks: [{ name: 'seat ventilation' }], // no error
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgQCYHkBGAVhAMbAA8MAfFALxQDeAUFFANoDSUAlklANYQQAewBmsKAhRQuEAB5Yk2aQAMAJA16iIcKADkEAWwgBfDQHIAIhHNQAPlHMAxOOZMqWrKAH59RiJ6sAFwyALohMJyhUPKKylDCRKTAPrCIqBhYeElklFE0EVEA3EwmJUy8WHCiCCTQAOLchobcJPyMnkj+1iEowHC8AOYlrF3GLr39QyUmTBVIVTV1UADCCLrMo90QkwNIw53+E1B9ewesYAN1IUgArob4OiNQg00tbSghjc2t-GyhMzmJGEqBSwBI6wi6XQmBwBGIuTWcBo9E2UDGO0cSPR-nMABpPJdWpiAGwATgJrFePw+ITYDBxxhC5hQEEwUAAbhAFtxMtwQbYTKE8VBSiUgA)

Comment: This is a great answer - BUT what if  a gimmick had a property `availableFrom: Date`. This will break...

Comment: @sandrooco does it? Works for me [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgQCYHkBGAVhAMbAA8MAfFALxQDeAUFFANoDSUAlklANYQQAewBmsKAhRQuEAB5Yk2aQAMAJA16iIcKADkEAWwgBfDQHIAIhHNQAPlHMAxOOZMqWrKAH59RiJ6sAFwyALohMJyhUPKKylDCRKTAPrCIqBhYeElklFE0EVEA3EwmJUy8WHCiCCTQAOLchobcJPyMnkj+1iEowHC8AOYlrF3GLr39QyOSAG4I3Bj4aBAuwoYhlpgQJSZMFUhVNXVQAMIIusyj3RCTA0jDnf4TUH33j6xgA3UhSACuhnwOhmgyaLTaKBCjWarX4bFCu32JGEqBSwBIFwi6XQ22yxFy5zgNHoVygY1ujkJZP85gANJ4vq0KQA2ACc9NYoJhEJCbAY1OMIXMKAgmCgswgh0WmG4KLpcwWSxWaw2ZIgAHcoFssAAKACUUBMoXpZSYQA)

Comment: Try to add the code below. Interestingly enought this breaks in typescriptlang.org/play but seems to work on stackblitz?!

const format = (d: Date)=> d.toString();

console.log(format(tcar.gimmicks[0].availableFrom));

Comment: Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXrGVm)

Comment: That is wild stuff - thanks. :)

Comment: @sandrooco If you will have some types that you would like to ignore, just add those in `IgnoredTypes`

Comment: do you have any pointers on how this could work with optional properties?

Comment: can you provide an example