# Typescript: Omitting translated properties - Deeptranslate

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I have the following type to 'translate' an object in TypeScript (original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76407242/typescript-omitting-translated-properties)):

```
 /**
 * TranslatedObject works with conditional type inference and template literal types
 * It will remove properties with the language suffixes (De, Fr, It and En) and simply return the non-suffixed property
 * This is done recursively for all properties whose types extend from `object` excluding {@link IgnoredTypes}
 *
 * @example
 * 
 * interface Car {
 *   nameDe: string,
 *   nameFr: string,
 *   nameIt: string,
 *   nameEn: string,
 *   price: number
 * }
 * type TranslatedCar = TranslatedObject<Car>;
 * 
 *
 * Result:
 * 
 * type TranslatedCar = {
 *   name: string;
 *   price: number;
 * }
 * 
 */
export type TranslatedObject<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof T]: TranslatedObject<T[I]> } : {
  [K in keyof T as K extends `${infer Name}${'De' | 'Fr' | 'It' | 'En'}` ? Name : K]: T[K] extends object ? (T[K] extends IgnoredTypes[number] ? T[K] : TranslatedObject<T[K]>) : T[K];
};

// IgnoredTypes is needed because `Date` for example extends `object` but Date won't have any translated properties
type IgnoredTypes = [Date];
```

The problem I'm facing now is with optional nested properties. For example if car has an optional property 'gimmicks'.

```
     
      interface Car {
        nameDe: string,
        nameFr: string,
        nameIt: string,
        nameEn: string,
        price: number,
        gimmicks?: Gimmick[]
      }

      type Gimmick = {
       nameDe: string,
       nameEn: string
      }

      type TranslatedCar = TranslatedObject<Car>;
      
     
      // Result:
      
      type TranslatedCar = {
        name: string;
        price: number;
        gimmicks: {name: string}[]
      }


const car: TranslatedCar = {
  name: 'carname',
  price: 15,
  gimmicks: [{name: 'gimmick 1'}]
}
```

With this I get the following error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Gimmick'.(2353)
```

What do I need to change, that the TranslateObject type also deep translates optional properties?

Comment: Not sure why you put `Array<unknown>` in your ignored types; you should remove it and just leave `Date` or any type you truly don't want to drill into.  Your type is already recursive and should work for nested properties, except for the weirdness with arrays.  Mostly all you have to do is add a homomorphic mapped type specifically for arrays (because you don't want to change the names of array methods and keys), as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WJ3ygw).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @jcalz sorry for the late response. removing Array<unknown> worked. The issue i'm facing now is with optional types. For example if gimmicks is optional 
`
interface Car {
  nameDe: string,
  nameFr: string,
  nameIt: string,
  nameEn: string,
  price: number,
  gimmicks?: Gimmick[]
}

const car: TranslatedCar = {
  name: 'test',
  price: 15,
  gimmicks: [{
    name: 'mirror'
  }]
}
`

Then you'll get the error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Gimmick'.(2353)

Comment: You mean the problem is with something you didn’t use in your example code? That seems out of scope for the question. I’m happy to write up my original suggestion as an answer and you can post your added requirement as a new question post. Or you could [edit] this post to capture your additional requirement, but then I don’t know if I could commit to helping, especially if the time to iterate on this question takes weeks. How shall we proceed?

Comment: @jcalz I have edited the original question. I'll try to answer folloup questions as fast as possible.

Comment: This is disappointing. You incorporated my suggestion for your original question into the new version (homomorphic mapped type for the array case) and you didn't credit me for it. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a one-on-one tech support session; it's supposed to also be a resource for future readers. Just because *you* no longer have the original issue, doesn't mean it's no longer needed in the question. At this point I would strongly suggest reverting to the original version, letting me answer it, and then you open a new question with this version. If that happens I'll re-engage.